# http.Redirect is not working with nginx config

Tags: vue.js, http, go, nginx

My http.Redirect is as below:

```
http.Redirect(iWri, pRq, "/report/"+UD.TID+"/_report/last_report.html", http.StatusFound)
```

Here `UD.TID = 2022066A4KIFTXUUP2WQO7`, or something like that, but my Router code is like below:

```golang
oRouter.PathPrefix(
    "/report/{id:[0-9]{6}[A-Za-z2-7=]{16}}/{path:.*}",
).Methods("GET").Handler(
    mwBaseCompressed.ThenFunc(apiParam.ReportServerHandler()),
)
```

My folder structure where the `last_report.html` is stored is as below:

```
"/Users/myname/projbuild/prod/project_v2/_var/QCACHE/2022/06/6A4KIFTXUUP2WQO7/_report/last_report.html"
```

The above combination is working fine when we run frontend (vue) and backend (go) on local or dev server, means the string `2022066A4KIFTXUUP2WQO7` somehow get split into `2022/06/6A4KIFTXUUP2WQO7` and report get displayed.

BUT on the production server we are using Nginx server and nginx conf is s below for /report,

```
location /report/ { alias /home/admin/_var/QCACHE/; }
```

with Nginx the string `2022066A4KIFTXUUP2WQO7` doesn't get split and remains same so application can't show report.
Same is working fine with haproxy.

Answer (score 0):

Added below block in my nginx.config, basically i found out all the routing calls from my main.go (oRouter.Handle) and then used them as below to configure in nginx,

```
location ~ ^/(api|ufile|report|uad|pimg|xml|constants.js|test){
                               proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999;
                               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                               add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
                             }
```